# Is there a second location where Spelunky saves data?

Tags: spelunky

Does anyone know where Spelunky saves the data that is not in the folder it extracts to?

It seems like Spelunky doesn't let me move its folders to other computers and keep the shortcuts I worked so hard to get.

Comment: I assume you mean _Spelunky_ for [tag:Windows]?

Comment: Correct. Is there even Spelunky for mac/Linux?

Comment: No, but I wanted to be sure for the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this wiki page](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Portable_Spelunky), Spelunky saves game data (this includes which minigames and shortcuts have been opened) in the registry, specifically:

> To save the state information, export the "834524" key under Game
> Maker.
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Game Maker\Scores\834524] "Rank1"="[a
> whole buncha letters]"
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Game
> Maker\Scores\834524] "Rank2"="[a whole buncha letters]"
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Game Maker\Scores\834524] "Rank3"="[a
> whole buncha letters]"
>
> etc...

Now, this appears to hold for the 0.9x versions of the game according to the wiki, but may very well hold for the latest version as well (1.1, from what I gather).

The wiki also points out that the [portable version of Spelunky](http://mossmouth.com/forums/index.php?topic=1219.0) is more friendly in the game-state department, by saving all game information alongside the actual game. It also lets you import your current data from the registry, according to its feature list.